# iOS HealthKit set Read Only Permission

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, healthkit, hkhealthstore

is it possible to set just read only permission for HealthKit?

I tried removing NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription in the plist thinking this allows me to just have the read permission but this will crash the app. (I don't like to include this since I don't have any good reason to use the write permission).

Comment: Have you added NSHealthShareUsageDescription in the plist?

Comment: Yes @NSAdi, but it seems to require both keys

Comment: Although not mentioned anywhere explicitly, it does seem like you'll need both of those keys.

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought. I attempted to remove the Update Usage key thinking this will enable me to just have read only permission.

Comment: You should file a bug with Apple about the issue, since it should be possible to only specify the description that is relevant to your use of HealthKit.